# Which source control uses a "s." prefix on its filenames?

Tags: version-control

I found what appears to be an old source repository for some source code that I need to resurrect. But I have no idea what source control tools were used to generate and manage this source repository. In the directory, all of the files have a "s." prefixed to the file name. Without knowing the format in these files, I cannot manually extract the source code with any degree of accuracy. And even if I did, manually extracting the source code would be very time consuming and error prone.

What source/version control system prefixes its source files with "s." when it stores the source file in its repository directory?

How can I effectively extract the latest source code from this repository directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `s.` prefix is characteristic of SCCS, the Source Code Control System. The code for that is probably still proprietary, but GNU has the [CSSC](http://www.gnu.org/software/cssc/) project which can manipulate SCCS files. It tracks changes per-file in revisions, known as 'deltas'.

SCCS is the official revision control system for POSIX; you can find the commands documented on the Open Group site (but the file format is not specified there, AFAICT):

- [`admin`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/admin.html)
- [`delta`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/delta.html)
- [`get`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/get.html)
- [`prs`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/prs.html)
- [`rmdel`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/rmdel.html)
- [`sact`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sact.html)
- [`unget`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/unget.html)
- [`val`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/val.html)
- [`what`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/what.html)

The file format is not specified by POSIX. The manual page for `get` says:

> The SCCS files shall be files of an unspecified format.

The original SCCS command set included some extras not recorded by POSIX:

- cdc — change delta commentary (for changing the checkin comments for a delta)
- comb — combine, effectively for merging deltas
- help — no prefix; the wasn't any other `help` program at the time.  Commands generate error codes such as `cm3` and `help` interpreted them.
- sccsdiff — difference between two deltas of a file

Most systems now have a single command, `sccs`, which takes the operation name and then options.  Often, the files were placed into an `./SCCS/` subdirectory and extracted from that as required, and the `sccs` front-end would handle name expansion, adding `s.` or `SCCS/s.` to the start of the file names.

For extracting the latest version of the source code, use `get`.

```
get s.*
sccs get s.*
```

These will get the default version of each file, and the default default is the latest version of the file.

If you need to make changes, use:

```
get -e s.filename.c
...make changes...
delta -y'Why you made the changes' s.filename.c
get s.filename.c
```

Note that the files 'lose' the `s.` prefix for the working file names, rather like RCS (Revision Control System) files lose the `,v` suffix for the working file names.  If you've not come across that, accept that it was different when SCCS and RCS were created, back in the late 70s or early 80s.

Comment: thanks to both Robin and Jonathan for your comments. That is what I needed. I was able to install gnu cssc which supports the 'sccs get' command. I was able to resurrect the source in this repository very easily. Thanks again guys...

Answer (score 2):

SCCS uses an s. prefix. But it might not be the only one!

I never knew this knowledge would come in useful some day!